# PyQt not showing QSystemTrayIcon on XFCE / Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus

Tags: python, ubuntu, pyqt

```
#!/usr/bin/python
#
#  GUI.py
#  
#  Copyright 2015 Ognjen Galic <gala@thinkpad>
#  
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
#  it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
#  the Free Software Foundation; either version 2 of the License, or
#  (at your option) any later version.
#  
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#  
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software
#  Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston,
#  MA 02110-1301, USA.
#  
#  

 ################################# UI START ############################

from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
import sys

try:
    _fromUtf8 = QtCore.QString.fromUtf8
except AttributeError:
    def _fromUtf8(s):
        return s

try:
    _encoding = QtGui.QApplication.UnicodeUTF8
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig, _encoding)
except AttributeError:
    def _translate(context, text, disambig):
        return QtGui.QApplication.translate(context, text, disambig)

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("MainWindow"))
        MainWindow.resize(200, 100)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_fromUtf8("Example"))
        self.main_widget = QtGui.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.main_widget.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("main_widget"))
        self.horizontalLayout = QtGui.QHBoxLayout(self.main_widget)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("horizontalLayout"))
        self.exit_button = QtGui.QPushButton(self.main_widget)
        self.exit_button.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("exit_button"))
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.exit_button)
        self.trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png")) # <<<<<<<<<<< WONT SHOW
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.main_widget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

        # --------------------------- QT ACTION BIND START #############

        self.exit_button.clicked.connect(self.exit_main)

        # --------------------------- QT ACTION BIND STOP ##############

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        self.exit_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exit", None))

        # --------------------------- MAIN FUNCTIONS START #############

    def exit_main(self):
        sys.exit()

        # --------------------------- MAIN FUNCTIONS STOP ##############

def initUI():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

 ################################### UI STOP ###########################

def main():
    pass

initUI() # Initialize the UI
main() # Run the MAIN
```

Here is my source, Python is 2.7, amd64, Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial Xerus with Xfce 4.12, PyQt4

The like that is supposed to show the system tray icon:

```
self.trayIcon = QtGui.QSystemTrayIcon(QtGui.QIcon("icon.png"))
```

Is doing nothing. Yet if ran on another .py file with manual `trayIcon.show()` it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You missing the show part :)

```
self.exit_button.clicked.connect(self.exit_main)

# --------------------------- QT ACTION BIND STOP ##############

self.trayIcon.show()
```

This works for me

Comment: Nice. It worked nice. I'm idiot that i missed that. Thanks!